# Clear multiple column values in DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a data table with 3 columns namely `Column1, Column2` and `Column3` with data. I can clear single column values using the following code.

```
dtTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().
       ToList().
       ForEach(r => r["Column1"] = DBNull.Value);
```

I need to clear two columns of the same datatable; is there any method to specify two column names in the same line of code?

Comment: Just fyi: `List.ForEach` is not LINQ at all, it's a method of `List<T>` which was aalready there before LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as that :)

```
dtTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().ToList().ForEach(r => 
{
   r["Column1"] = DBNull.Value;
   r["Column2"] = DBNull.Value;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `ToList.ForEach` just to be able to modify the values. You are creating a brand new collection which is completely redundant. Instead you simply need a loop.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dtTable.Rows)
{
     // presuming nullable int-columns
     row.SetField<int?>("Column1", null);
     row.SetField<int?>("Column2", null);
}
```

The [`SetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336477%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method also supports nullable types. *"If value is null, the SetField method converts the null value to Value in the underlying DataColumn."*

Comment: `DBNull.Value` and `null` are different isn't it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: `SetField` supports nullable types. _"If value is null, the SetField method converts the null value to Value in the underlying DataColumn.
"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for the info. Is there any other method without using the loop?

Comment: @TechDo: Why don't you like loops? They are the most efficient way to solve this problem and they are readable as well. In general LINQ should not be used for updates (apart from Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entitites) but only for queries. That's why it's name has a `q` at the end ;-)

Comment: Good suggestions - both of omitting new list creation and usage of SetField

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use `;` to separate the multiple fields inside `{}`. Try the below

```
dtTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().ToList().ForEach(r => {r["Column1"] = DBNull.Value; r["Column2"] = DBNull.Value;});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
dtTable.Clear();
```

It will clear your all data but not columns.